# Start new ionic app with tab using cmd is not working

Tags: ionic-framework, terminal, ionic2

I'm trying to start my first ionic app. it says I should type in "ionic start myApp tabs". When I do that, it gets the directory, downloads, and extracts tabs starter and tries to install dependencies. The problem is when installing the dependencies it shows the code below with error and doesn't start the app

I've tried restarting the cmd console, running it as admin and clearing npm. doesn't still work
[image]

[image: Here's the error]

Comment: try this cmd: `npm cache clean --force` and try this: `npm i -g ionic`

Comment: @user9088454 i've done that, what next?

Comment: create again project

Comment: @user9088454 ok its working now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this cmd: `npm cache clean --force` and try this: `npm i -g ionic`

then create a project again.